# Exception when accessing CAS login page deployed in JBoss

Tags: jboss, spring-security, cas

i'm trying to deploy a CAS web app in jboss wildfly and when accessing the login page its throwing a exception.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/log4jConfiguration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [log4j.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:/content/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml

how can i resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We have had success by commenting out the log4jInitialization bean in the log4jConfiguration.xml file as follows:

```
<!--
     <bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
         <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
         <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
         <property name="arguments">
             <list>
                 <value>${log4j.config.location:classpath:log4j.xml}</value>
                 <value>${log4j.refresh.interval:60000}</value>
             </list>
         </property>
    </bean>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your log4j.xml file can be located by cas. Add/modify the file path in your cas.properties file.